# web3.js calling transfer function return Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ethereum, web3js

I'm currently using web3.js to use a function on form submit, which is `transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)`

I'm able to call contract function, but I get Erro: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function trying to use the transfer function, suppling both to address and amount of token.

Here part of my code:

```
function sendtoken(to, amount){

    var to = to; 
    var amount = amount; 
    var settx = contract.transfer(to,amount);

    return settx;
}
```

Calling it (don't worry, my contract correctly called in contract var

```
var formData = getFormObj("tokeform");

console.log(formData.destinationtoke);
console.log(formData.amounttoke);
var tx = sendtoken(destinationtoke, amounttoke);
var tx = JSON.stringify(tx, null, "  ");

console.log(tx);
```

This is where I get the error. Here the contract function:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    if (genesisAddress[_to]) throw;

    if (balances[msg.sender] < _value) throw;

    if (balances[_to] + _value < balances[_to]) throw;

    if (genesisAddress[msg.sender]) {
        minedBlocks = block.number - initialBlockCount;
        if(minedBlocks % 2 != 0){
            minedBlocks = minedBlocks - 1;
        }

        if (minedBlocks < 23652000) {
            availableAmount = rewardPerBlockPerAddress*minedBlocks;
            totalMaxAvailableAmount = initialSupplyPerAddress - availableAmount;
            availableBalance = balances[msg.sender] - totalMaxAvailableAmount;
            if (_value > availableBalance) throw;
        }
    }
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}
```

Any ideas why I get this error? I seems to be suppling right element. I'm not used to web3.js at all, and I thought I could call this function same as I fo withs others on current contract that return correct data, as balance of token and rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(formData.destinationtoke);
console.log(formData.amounttoke);
var tx = sendtoken(destinationtoke, amounttoke);
```

To :

```
console.log(formData.destinationtoke);
console.log(formData.amounttoke);
var tx = sendtoken(formData.destinationtoke, formData.amounttoke);
```

Magic, now returning data

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741374/web3-eth-sendtransaction-sending-to-random-address

Comment: I successfully sent tx but it go to random address -_-